# Swift Playground in Xcode - TapGestureRecognizer to UILabel not working

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, swift-playground

I am creating a Swift Playground in Xcode and I have a problem with putting a TapGestureRecognizer to an UILabel...

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

  override func loadView() {

    func tapped() {

        print("The label was tapped!")

    }

    let label11 = UILabel()
    label11.frame = CGRect(x: -350, y: 360, width: 350, height: 20)
    label11.text = "name."
    label11.textColor = .black
    label11.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addSubview(label11)

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tapped")
    label11.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're creating the view controller programmatically since you're operating solely in `loadView` (where you correctly did not call `super`), which requires you to create the actual `view` of that controller.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        view = UIView()

        let label11 = UILabel()
        label11.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 360, width: 350, height: 20)
        label11.text = "name."
        label11.textColor = .yellow
        label11.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(label11)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        label11.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func tapped() {
        print("The label was tapped!")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Alternatively, you can replicate a non-programmatic view controller by using `viewDidLoad` (which requires you to call super).

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label11 = UILabel()
        label11.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 360, width: 350, height: 20)
        label11.text = "name."
        label11.textColor = .yellow
        label11.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(label11)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        label11.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    @objc func tapped() {
        print("The label was tapped!")
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Also, your `origin-x` value was out of bounds which is why you may not have seen the label and you were missing `@objc` syntax which is required in Swift 4.

Comment: For anyone who may not know, to see the view controller in the Playground, go to `View` > `Assistant Editor` > `Show Assistant Editor`

Comment: The `viewDidLoad` solution here is the better approach.